# How do the different compression levels of gzip differ?

Tags: zip, compression, gzip, zlib

I am trying to better understand how different compression levels  (1-9) of gzip differ in the way that encoding is implemented.

I've looked the zlib C source code and it seems that it has to do with how exhaustive the search for the longest matching string is, but looking for more specific information.

For example, do the levels yield any differences in the assignment of Huffman codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The levels differ only in how hard deflate looks for matching strings, as you observed. The Huffman coding is done on a chosen fixed number of symbols (literals and length/distance pairs), producing a "block", where that number is defined by the memory level, not the compression level. The Huffman codes generated will necessarily differ, since the symbols being coded will differ.

The choice of memory level also has some effect on compression, as a larger number of symbols spreads the cost of the code description for a block over more symbols, but too many symbols may prevent adaptation of the Huffman codes to local changes in the statistics of the symbols. The default memory level is 8 (resulting in 16,383 symbols per block), since testing indicated that that gave better compression than level 9 (32,767 symbols per block). However your mileage may vary.

Comment: Thanks! Am I right in thinking that if repeated strings tend to occur farther back (but within the same block) it will take more memory to store the greater distance? E.g., assuming the same degree of (total) repetition in a file, having repeated strings occur on average 50 bytes back will yield a slightly better compression ratio than having repeated strings occur on average 500 bytes? Or is the memory allocated for distances fixed?

Comment: It takes more bits for farther distances. A distance of 50 will take 4 bits plus a Huffman code (at least one bit), whereas a distance of 500 will take 7 bits plus a Huffman code. The size of the Huffman codes will depend on how often those bins show up as distances compared to the other bins.

Answer (score 0):

From what I recall, yes, it is mainly based on the size of the buffer you'll be allocating. The larger the buffer, the better you can compress. If you can allocate a buffer with a size of about `input file size × 1.2`, then, in most cases, you will get the best compression possible with Huffman.

The reason is that the Huffman table will encompass all the bytes with the best possible outcome when you have such a large buffer. When the algorithm runs out of buffer space, then it needs to reset its table (there is a code in the stream added for that) and that means you start a new encoding table from scratch, which means you lose bytes to redesign that new table...

Although there are cases where resetting can be beneficial (i.e. many bytes set to value X in the first half of your file, and then many more that have value Y in the second half), it is rare that would happens.